# Is it Zakat, if you donate to different charity organizations?

Tags: zakat

I have for sometime now willingly, donated money monthly to different charity organizations, that are specialized in helping humans, and animals for a better life.

Is it seen as Zakat?

Another question of mine is. 
I am in a poor economic situation, and there will be a time where I cannot keep helping these organizations. How will the best way to keep doing Zakat for me?

Thank you, for your time and help.

Comment: Please note that in Islam we have two ways for donating: **Zakat** is an obligatory "delivery" which is well defined in the fiqh books and will need much more elaboration to explain it. While **Sadaqah** is a free donation. Both can be given to some kind of *people* (so non-Humans are excluded) who are clearly described in Verse (9:60) http://legacy.quran.com/9/60. So any of them would count if they are given the right way and to the allowed people!

Answer (score 2):

9: 60

إِنَّمَا الصَّدَقَاتُ لِلْفُقَرَاءِ وَالْمَسَاكِينِ وَالْعَامِلِينَ عَلَيْهَا وَالْمُؤَلَّفَةِ قُلُوبُهُمْ وَفِي الرِّقَابِ وَالْغَارِمِينَ وَفِي سَبِيلِ اللَّهِ وَابْنِ السَّبِيلِ ۖ فَرِيضَةً مِنَ اللَّهِ ۗ وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ

Zakah  expenditures  are  only  for  the  poor  and  for  the  needy  and  for  those  employed  to collect  [zakah]  and  for  bringing  hearts  together  [for  Islam]  and  for  freeing  captives  [or slaves]  and  for  those  in  debt  and  for  the  cause  of Allah and  for  the  [stranded]  traveler  - an  obligation  [imposed]  by Allah .  And Allah is  Knowing  and  Wise.

You can give the zakat for just the types mentioned above. Animals are not of the types you can give it zakat.

The zakat have two conditions first you should have the money for one year, moon year.  And you should have more than or equal 85 gram of gold ( so it is depend on gold value ). And you give 2.5% of your money ( 1/40 of your money )

Comment: That's a nice and brief answer and explanation about Zakat! May Allah bless you!